# Non-uniform Distributions for Haskell data types

Tags: haskell, random, non-uniform-distribution

The [random](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random) package contains a type class `Uniform` for uniformly distributed types.
This works for types like:

```
data Coin = Heads | Tails
```

But let's say I want to model a set of things with a non-uniform distribution, for example by adding the possibility of the coin landing on its side:

```
data Coin = Heads | Tails | Side
```

Now I could still implement `Uniform` with a non-uniform distribution in its implementation but that would be lying to the implicit rules of `Uniform`.

Do I have to just use a standalone function or is there some type class for the concept of an "actual" distribution?

This type class would be useful in the context of an RPG where you could have some types

```
data Rarity = Common | Rare
data DropType = Club | Sword
```

where the chances of getting a `Rare` and it being a `Sword` might be lower than the other values.
But the concept of drawing a value from the set of all values of that type is still the same for `Rarity` and `DropType` which is why this looks like a job for type classes to me.

Comment: [`Arbitrary`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Arbitrary) seems to be the best fit. Most people use it only in QuickCheck, but IMO it makes sense for these kind of applications too. There was/is [a discussion on whether QuickCheck's generators should be detached from the main package](https://github.com/nick8325/quickcheck/issues/209).

Comment: another option might be [`Data.Random.Distribution.Categorical`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.7.7/docs/Data-Random-Distribution-Categorical.html).  looks like it uses `random` underneath to do the actual sampling, and has a variety of other distributions that look sensibly parameterised

Comment: @leftaroundabout That ties up the generation with the type itself, making it awkward to produce distributions with different skews in different contexts, no? Like, "swords this enemy drops are much more likely to be made of silver". Ordinary functions seem more flexible to me.

Answer (score 3):

One option is using *random-fu*, which offers [a categorical distribution](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.7.7/docs/Data-Random-Distribution-Categorical.html). A quick example:

```
import Data.Random
import Data.Random.Distribution.Categorical
import Data.Random.Sample

data Coin = Heads | Tails | Side deriving Show

-- set up distribution, weights don't have to sum to 1
coin :: Categorical Double Coin
coin = fromList [(0.5, Heads), (0.5, Tails), (0.001, Side)]

-- draw a single sample from the distribution
main = sample coin >>= print
```